# Can I boot Windows XP from a separate hard drive (connected via USB) on a Windows 7 machine?

Tags: windows-7, boot

Hope this isn't a duplicate question. I have a new computer with Windows 7 64-bit installed as the OS. Can I boot into Windows XP from a different hard drive connected via a USB port? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frankly, I wouldn't want to, nor would I recommend it - USB ports are orders of magnitude slower than SATA ports.

It can be done (though it's unsupported), but I would suggest you're better off getting a Caddy system and just swapping SATA hard drives.  Better still, run Virtual PC or VMWare and XP in a virtual machine (if you get/upgrade to Windows 7 Ultimate or even just business, it comes with XP Mode - a virtual PC install of XP that puts installed programs in the Windows 7 start menu).

reference:
http://www.ngine.de/index.jsp?pageid=4176